# Cast Any to a List in Kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin, object

I cast this any type

```
 data: {
            amount: 10,
            product: {
                goodsName: String,
                barcode: String    
            }
        }
```

to list,
So, I put the data

```
val detailsAsData: Map<String, Any> = menuDetailMapper.detailAsMap(data)

fun <T> T.serializeToMap(): Map<String, Any> {
    return convert()
}
inline fun <I, reified O> I.convert(): O {
    val json = gson.toJson(this)
    return gson.fromJson(json, object : TypeToken<O>() {}.type)
}
```

In that result,

```
{amount=10.0, product={barcode=12377784597, goodsName=cheese}}
```

When transforming an any type variable, if there is a value of an any type, how can I transform it?
Like, product.
If I use the serializeToMap above, the value becomes Any type, but I want to know how to change it when the value is in the form of any object, not string or int.

Comment: `I'm going to convert an object without a data class into a list.` What do you mean here?

Comment: @ArpitShukla Like this, List<Object> list = getList(); return (List<Customer>) list;

Comment: What you show seems to be json, which has nothing to do with kotlin. If you are asking how to do random json transformations, you'll need to pick a json handling library, like jackson, moshi or kotlinx-serialization-json , for example for jackson: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-to-jsonnode . But depending on your use case, deserializing into a data class, transforming those data structures into the new ones and serializing might be much easier and less bug-prone.

Comment: @PolarisNation are you using JSON as a way to represent your intent because you're unsure about how to express what you want in Kotlin, or are you actually talking about reading/writing JSON here? Please update the question to reflect that because it's hard to tell what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @somethingsomething Okay, thanks. I'll try to serialize and deserialize the data

Comment: @Joffrey I'm sorry for the lack of explanation. There is an Any type of variable, and I'm trying to make it like the list below.